# multipte ListTile substring

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I made a page that contains data from a local json file. I display the data but I need more than one subtitle. How can I do that? I need at least 4 or 5.
I can use something else I don't need to use ListTile.
I hope you can help me.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by saying "more subtitle"? Do you need multiline for subtitle space? If so list tile has `isThreeLine` option and you can use that. If you need more than three lines, you can solve that using a column.

Comment: I need at least 4 or 5. `ListTile(
                  title: Text(showData[index]['ILAC ADI']),
                  subtitle: Text(showData[index]['ETKIN MADDE']), ` I am currently displaying the data like that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ListTile, just use a Column widget, you can then put as many rows in it as you want.

edited with example code

```
return Column(
  children: [
    Text(showData[index]['ILAC ADI']),
    Text(showData[index]['ETKIN MADDE'],
    Text(showData[index]['SOMETHING_ELSE'],
  ]
);
```

Of course, you can style each line differently, adding padding, bigger size text, bold, etc...

Comment: I am getting data from a local json file (I copied it inside my project files.)   `return ListTile(
                  title: Text(showData[index]['ILAC ADI']),
                  subtitle: Text(showData[index]['ETKIN MADDE']),   ` I am using this like that to get the data. I need more titles to show more data.